# unable to load the module for vfat support with modprobe

Tags: modprobe

I'm doing a lab in this course and I'm asked to : "Load the module for vfat support; does it have any dependencies ?"

The answer for this lab is these commands :

```
modprobe vfat

modinfo vfat 

lsmod | grep vfat
```

However, on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine when I run 1st and 3rd commands, I don't get any output and when I run :

```
modinfo vfat
```

I get

```
modinfo: ERROR: Module vfat not found.
```

How should I approach this lab ?

Comment: It looks like there is no `vfat` in Ubuntu 5.0 kernel any more. But FAT FS works.

Comment: What does `grep CONFIG_VFAT /boot/config-$(uname -r)`? if you see `CONFIG_VFAT_FS=y` then afaik it means that your running kernel has vfat built-in (rather than loadable as a module).

Comment: @Pilot6 How do I load `FAT FS` ? I've tried `modprobe fat` but then when I do `lsmod` it is not shown.


@steeldriver yes

`grep CONFIG_VFAT /boot/config-$(uname -r)` returns `CONFIG_VFAT_FS=y`

so that's why I can't load it then, allright, thanks.

Comment: Can you recommend me any other module I can try to load and that would actually load ?
I need this so that when I come back to repeating my labs for my exam - the lab does work and I can continue with other labs :]